# Python detect kill request

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit

I have a python 3 script and it runs on boot. And it work with some resources I want it free on exit.

How can I manage that script is going to exit if I'm killing it with `kill -6 $PID`.

Or any other ideas about how to send exit command and detect it in script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [signal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) module is what you are looking for.

```
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)

signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, handler)
```

Within the handler function you could terminate with `sys.exit()`.

However, it is more common to use SIGINT (that's what happens when you press CTRL+C in the terminal) or SIGTERM to terminate a program. If you don't have cleanup code you don't need to write a single line of code to handle SIGINT - by default it raises a *KeyboardInterrupt* exception which, if not caught (that's a reason why you should never use blank `except:` statements), causes your program to terminate.

Comment: I've decided to use SIGINT with KeyboardInterrupt. Thanks a lot